# docpad: Use partials after rendering?

Tags: docpad

I'm building a plugin to generate site-wide menus; the data for these menus comes from scanning the rendered DOM for *.html.md files; but I only use the menu in one place (root of the site).

Plugin currently generates each page's part of this menu in `writeBefore`, which works fine as I walk the collection, handle each document, and write a file into the partials directory.

But since the docs have all been rendered already by that time, the <%- @partial('foo.html')%> call in my index.html.eco doesn't work unless I run `docpad generate` twice.

I assumed that if I set `renderPasses` to a value > 1, then the partials would get picked up on the > 1 pass, but that doesn't happen.

Is there an event I can use that's *after* an initial render (so there's a DOM to parse) but *before* partials get rendered?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `renderDocument` event (fired for each document, plus for each layout the document has) or the `renderAfter` event. But I think you may have the same problem.

What specifically is the reasoning of having your menu require the rendered content of other files? As you could use the [text plugin](http://docpad.org/p/text) to be able to render meta data attributes just the same, and have those meta data attributes accessible before render. E.g.

```
---
someMarkdown: "<t render="markdown">*hello*</t>"
---
```

then in your menu or whatever

```
<ul><% for page in @getCollection('html').toJSON(): %>
  <li><%- page.someMarkdown %></li>
<% end %></ul>
```

And that will work just as expected with the meta data property being rendered with markdown by the text plugin.